# How to implement a custom application protocol over TCP using the spring framework?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I've been trying to figure out for a while now what is the correct approach to implement a custom application protocol over TCP within the spring framework. Can you guys address me on this topic?

I've done different research, and spring integration with tcp connectors seems to be the solution to go with, but I'm not sure because in doing research I haven't found much material on this, so by itself I don't understand if maybe "I'm searching in the wrong way".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/ip.html#tcp-codecs

If one of the standard serializer/deserializers does not provide for the message demarcation you need, simply create custom versions.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/ip.html#custom-serializers-and-deserializers

> If your data is not in a format supported by one of the standard deserializers, you can implement your own; you can also implement a custom serializer.

> To implement a custom serializer and deserializer pair, implement the `org.springframework.core.serializer.Deserializer` and `org.springframework.core.serializer.Serializer` interfaces.

> When the deserializer detects a closed input stream between messages, it must throw a `SoftEndOfStreamException`; this is a signal to the framework to indicate that the close was "normal". If the stream is closed while decoding a message, some other exception should be thrown instead.

Comment: thanks for the help. I noticed that at the time I am writing the links you shared give 404

Comment: the link would appear to be this now
https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/ip/tcp-connection-factories.html